# Is it possible to filter ebay search results by shipping price

Tags: ebay

I live in quite a remote location. While it is reasonably simple to filter ebay search results so that I only see items that will ship to me, some of those will have a ludicrous shipping cost.

Is it possible to filter out items from a ebay search that have shipping price over a given value?

Comment: You can try geo-ship.com. It has this option

Comment: @ilan no it doesn't. I'm not asking to filter price+shipping, I'm asking to filter on _only_ shipping price. For auctions the current bid price is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such possibility, you have to look out for it manually. You can filter the items in terms of their actual cost only and not the additional shipping charges.

Also I think that the Shipping Charges are only calculated once you add a particular item to your cart, select the seller from who you would like to purchase and give your shipping address - so there is no possibility to filter items based on shipping costs as they are not calculated at that time at all.

The same item has various shipping charges based on from which seller you choose to buy, whether you have a premium account (or whatever they call it).

Answer (score 3):

You can try [auctionsensor ebay search tool](http://www.auctionsensor.com). You can search items by total price (list price + shipping fee). For example, if your max price is $50, and the item's list price is $40 and shipping fee is $11, auctionsensor will filter it out. It is free and no sign up required. Highly recommended.

Some of the auction sniper software also have advanced search/filter feature, for example, [JoyBidder eBay Auction Sniper](http://www.joybidder.com), you can click Ctrl+F to bring up a filter bar to allow more granular filtering capability. But it is not free and could be over-kill, if you just buy or sell on eBay occasionally.

Comment: Auctionsensor just has a small subset of search features already available on the official ebay site and there is nothing to indicate that sniper program can filter searches on shipping price.

Answer (score 1):

As several people have already pointed out, the simple answer is no.

There are a few filters eBay offers, however, that might get you pretty close.  Once you've searched for your item, go to the bottom of the left-side filter panel and select **"More refinements..."**

The first filter you will want to look at is *Free Shipping* (under *Delivery Options*).  The second filter you might want is *Item Location.*  This at least lets you look at sellers who are somewhat near you, which might affect their shipping price to you.

Another option is to build a list of sellers who have reasonable shipping to your location, and only search within those sellers inventory. (You can narrow your search to specific sellers from the *Advanced* search, but not from the filters tab).